# Is it legal to discuss exercise problems and solutions for a textbook?

Tags: books, legal-issues, website

Is it legal for a website to create an entry for a particular book, and add all the  exercise problems (not the question completely but just the question number) and create a reddit kind of discussion channel for people to discuss different solutions ?

Comment: Duplicate or at least similar: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38175/72855

Comment: Could you add a country tag, please? Answers might differ fundamentally depending on the jurisdiction.

Comment: This question should probably be on the law stackexchange.