# Is publishing a book with solutions to exercises in a math book that doesn't provide them legal?

Tags: mathematics, copyright

Is it legal to publish a book with solutions to all exercises proposed in a math book without solutions or an instructor´s manual provided? Is it necessary to ask any permission to do that?

An old post ([Solution manual and copyright?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/solution-manual-and-copyright) -- 8 years ago) discusses this issue  but I looking for a fresher view on the subject.

To make the situation more specific. Consider the U.S. jurisdiction and books under copyright protection. And 3 possibilities: (a) problem statements only referenced by question number and unpublished solutions; (b) problem statement reproduced and unpublished solutions; and (c) problem statements rephrased and unpublished solutions.

Comment: There are plenty of unspecified aspects here. What jurisdiction are you asking about? Is the book under copyright protection, or is there maybe even a license permitting derivative works? Are you reproducing the problems, or just providing solutions to numbered exercises? What do you expect to have changed in applicable copyright laws during the last  8 years?

Comment: @Anyon - Jurisdiction: US, book under copyright protection as most are. As this is a gray area, it depends on law interpretations by judges, and the understanding might change over time. Concerning the situations you posed, there is another one: rephrased problem statements and unpublished solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against this, but can't give a legal answer. I can give you some background to back up my recommendation and perhaps answer your specific questions.

First, copyright is civil law in the US and the copyright holder has to care enough to sue. If they do, then it can be expensive to defend. Another publisher wouldn't touch such a publication I think, as they generally want good relations with each other.

A more or less complete set of solutions is probably considered a derived work. Derived works are one of the rights reserved to copyright holders. I doubt that you could successfully claim fair use in such a work, especially if offered for sale, but maybe not in any case.

Another consideration in copyright is whether a work reduces the value of the original. Since a lot of professors would prefer that students not have easy access to solutions (it actually makes learning harder, not easier), they might not consider using such a book and thus reducing the value.

The above two points imply to me, at least, that such a work isn't fair use: too extensive, and reduces value. (More on the value below)

Paraphrasing is no defense against copyright in general.

So, you should ask the copyright holder. They might agree or not. They might agree that some, not all, solutions are ok, or not. They might publish the work themselves, which makes the issue go away altogether. They might agree to an instructor's guide that has hints but not solutions. Lots of possibilities, but doing it without permission is a risk.

Moreover, as I said above, having solutions available for a book makes it less valuable for students. People learn much more by doing exercises than by reading solutions. After all, most textbooks have some worked examples which permit reading solutions, but also have exercises, some quite deep, that don't have solutions. If a student is successful with those then they gain insight into a topic or a field. It is, in fact, what made me a mathematician and gave me insight into mathematical analysis. Without solving lots (lots) of problems I wouldn't have gained the same insight. Solutions seem like a service, but they are a disservice.

OTOH, one of my books has an available set of solutions, but I'm careful to provide it only to instructors who make a promise not to reproduce it. I think that promise is mostly honored. The book is such that the exercises are actually the most important feature. If a student can do all of them then they know the topic well. Struggling with them is a feature, not a bug.

---

There is another option, also, that would probably be acceptable to a copyright owner, even though it might be technically a derived work. Suppose you create additional exercises for a book and provide solutions to, say, half of them. So, a user would see some problems with solutions and others without. If you give it the same "chapter" outline that might make it a derived work, but might also be considered fair use. But it would enhance the value of the original, not diminish it. And enhance it both for the publisher and for the user. And, for elementary courses in math, such a problem/exercise set might be valuable independent of the text used. A publisher might actually be interested in such a thing. And the same might be done for books in some (many?) other fields such as CS.